# How can I make DataTables work with both a button in each row AND a selectable row?

Tags: datatables

With DataTables, I know how to get the following to work, independently:

1. Let a user click on a row and go to another page
2. Add a button to a row in one column and have it work

What I don't know how to do is to get them to work together. For a row, if the button is pressed then execute that function, otherwise, if another part of the row is selected, go to the next page.

Right now, when the button is pressed, both functionalities happen. How do I get it to work like I want to? I'd really like to avoid adding some "View" button on each row to go to the next page.

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/60383/how-to-have-button-click-event-separated-from-button-click-event

Comment: Hmm, maybe, but I'm not firing events, so don't have access to an event. I'm writing the button through a renderer: "<a href='javascript:updateUser(" + row.id + ",0)' class='" + cssClasses + "'>Disable</a>"

Comment: It turns out that yes, that does solve it. I just need to change the href=javascript:updateUser()"" to onclick="updateUser(event, id)" making sure that I include "event" as a parameter and then call e.stopPropagation() in that function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm putting @Priyank Panchal's comment reply into the answer. I changed

```
"<a href='javascript:updateUser(" + row.id + ",0)'>Disable</a>
```

to

```
"<a onclick='updateUser(event," + row.id + ",0)'>Disable</a>
```

including the event as a parameter and then in the updateUser() function, call

```
e.stopPropagation();
```